how to get UTM x/y from latitude and longitude
Hi i have this sql statment for x and y to convert from wgs84 to UTM format.
How can i get lati/long from a UTM x/y with diferent utm zones?
UTM x/y are saved as numbers.
    select t.sdo.sdo_point.y as y
  from (select sdo_cs.transform( 
                       sdo_geometry( 2001
                                   , 8307  --Longitude / Latitude (WGS 84)  SRID
                                   , SDO_POINT_TYPE(:P1061_LONGTITUDE,:P1061_LATITUDE,NULL)
                                   , null
                                   , null)
                             , 84032       -- UTM Zone 21 SRID
                            ) as sdo
        from dual
      ) t

select t.sdo.sdo_point.x as x
  from (select sdo_cs.transform( 
                       sdo_geometry( 2001
                                   , 8307  --Longitude / Latitude (WGS 84)  SRID
                                   , SDO_POINT_TYPE(:P1061_LONGTITUDE,:P1061_LATITUDE,NULL)
                                   , null
                                   , null)
                             , 84032       -- UTM Zone 21 SRID
                            ) as sdo
        from dual
      ) t

